# How to force Fortnite to use Easy Anti-Cheat instead of BattlEye?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I'm asking this because I always have to restart my laptop to disable virtualization, otherwise Fortnite won't get pass the BattlEye loading thingy. I read in some Fortnite update blog post that they now support Easy Anti-Cheat. Is there any way to force Fortnite to use this? Easy Anti-Cheat might be a solution to this problem (if my assumption that Easy Anti-Cheat does not require virtualization turned off is true).

I can't permanently keep virtualization turned on because I have some important VMs that I need, and it's a pain to keep restarting my laptop to just play a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem. To be honest, I don't even know if I was the one who fixed it. My Fortnite game needed updating, but I couldn't do it at the moment, so I enabled virtualization and started working (coding and making VMs sort of my hobby). The next day, I started the update. The game started normally. After I finished playing, I noticed that virtualization was still turned on! Fortnite started using EAC instead of BattlEye. This explains the fact that the EAC launcher came instead of the BattlEye launcher which I normally see.

So my conclusion is that if you turn on virtualization before updating or reinstalling Fortnite, it switches from EAC to BattlEye. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fortnite game directory Program Files/Epic Games/Fortnite/FortniteGame/Binaries/Win64, you will have a BE and EAC executable.  Replacing the BE executable with the EAC one fixes your problem.  This will get you to the lobby, but I have been informed it will kick you when you try to join a game.  Really irritating

Comment: By replacing, do you mean swapping the names? The executables are probably different (no, they are totally different) so obviously Fortnite will have a crash at some point :D

Answer (score 0):

FNBR.LEAKY
Okay.. Ive Been Looking At This For A Long Time (EAC can run without admin, BE cannot) apparently BE can be disabled with a trick that I found in the settings. If you go to your Fortnite directory, **FortniteGame>Binaries>Win64>BattlEye>** You Will Find ***BELauncher.ini***. You want to edit this, right click and edit. Look for

> SilentInstall=1

, change silent install to 0. This will open BE without direct install. File>Save. Now you can go back to The Win64 folder and open **FortniteClient-Win64-Shipping_EAC.exe**. Now EAC will open, wait until battleye opens. Click on do not ask again and click close. Fortnite should boot up. Now make sure silent install is back if you ever change your mind.